# No tests collected by pytest

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I have problem in importing pytest while writing a python code. "**import pytest** is grayed out.

Python is 3.8.3, Pycharm community edition.
pytest version 5.4.2, is successfully installed and can be seen in the project interpreter in pycharm. As well as I can see the installed path of pytest in python directory.

When running **py.test** command from console. It starts the test run shows **"collected 0 items"** and lastly ends with **"NO TESTS RAN IN 0.05s"**

If anyone running similar problems with some other packages kindly let me know.
**TIA...**

Comment: Can u post the code your trying to execute.

Comment: that  it is greyed out only indicates it is not being used in the file ... i suspect you are simply not aware of how to invoke pytest correctly (ie you don't *usually* import pytest into a file... but you can and sometimes need to)

Comment: Make sure you have named your tests (and test class if you use one) [correctly](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery). Also, you should use `pytest` instead of the deprecated `py.test`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the prompt and clear suggestions.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Thanks I now understand what you are trying to say. You are correct I am not aware of it. This is first time I am using Python and Pytest so many features I do not know how to implement :)

Comment: @Sushanth I got the answer now, It's working. But in future any issues I would rather post the code as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ApI-QA, can u share the solution with us it would be great to know.

Answer (score 1):

You simply run pytest from the commandline. There is no need to import pytest into a script. Take this Python script as an example:

```
def inc(x):
    return x + 1


def test_answer():
    assert inc(3) == 4
```

To run pytest on it, from the terminal (after changing to the right directory):

```
$ pytest
```

And you will then see the test outcome in the commandline as pytest automatically picks up the python scripts names test_*.py, where * is any name, e.g. test_increment.py. To have a test from your Python script run, name it with test_ as well to begin with.

Comment: As suggested I tried the same with my code and now I can see the output of pytest in console. This really helped as I am just beginner in Python will have these silly queries. Thanks Gustav.

Comment: That is my pleasure, glad it worked :) If you found my answer helpful, please consider to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Running pytest in the terminal is an option. In addition, Pycharm has integrated test suite for automatic discovery and collection of test tasks. You can use hotkey `ctrl+shift+10` to run the test tasks directly in current file  .

[image]